# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, deugging ) will not work properly

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio-3.2

Gradle sync failed when the firebase cloud messaging dependency was applied.

I've tried all the versions of FCM in app like 17.0.0, 17.3.2, 15.0.0, 16.0.1, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have the version number twice. Remove the `:15.0.0` from the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for a detailed explanation.

Replace your current FCM dependency with the following version -

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.3.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your implementation with this :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.3.4'irebase-messaging:17.3.4
```